# Null SqlCeTransaction at random times

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I have the following method:

```
public void SaveReferenceUpdates(ReferenceUpdatesDataContract updates)
{
    mTransaction = Connection.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        // Do all the updates to get the database inline with the contract.
        updates.UpdateFromContract();

        // Do all the deletes to get the database inline with the contract.
        updates.DeletesFromContract();

        try{mTransaction.Commit();}
        catch{throw;}
        mTransaction = null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        mTransaction.Rollback();
        mTransaction = null;
        throw;
    }
}
```

(I have taken out all my logging statements and collapsed a few methods to make this more readable.)

The weird thing is that sometimes (very very randomly) `mTransaction` is null when it gets to the commit step.  (Since this happens so randomly, I have not been able to see if it is null when it gets the transaction from the connection.)

This method is called in two places.  One is at the time the user logs into the my app and the other is when the user is inactive for a time (based on a timer that keys off of user input).

I am stumped as to what could cause `SqlCeTransaction` (`mTransaction`) to ever be null.  (The help does not say anything about BeginTransaction returning `null`.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this code called from multiple threads? That would explain the behavior (thread 2 starts a transaction, just before thread 1 finishes and sets it to null).

Comment: I think you are right.  I need to find a way to make sure only one thread gets to write at at time.

Comment: You could perhaps pass the transaction to the `UpdateFromContract()` and `DeleteFromContract()` methods, then `mTransaction` could be a local var.

Answer (score 0):

It could be right. Try lock(mTransaction) all block. it can slow down the program, but will surely be safe.